# What is the effect used in Tron Legacy to give voices a "digital" sound?

Tags: sound-effects, tron-legacy

In Tron Legacy several voices have some kind of effect applied that makes them sound "digital".

For example, the voice over at the start of this video.

It's subtle but it's there and a few other characters get it too.

How is this effect created?

Comment: Most likely some kind of reverb with an echo from what my limit ears can tell

Comment: It's also used in Star Wars I noticed.

Comment: Identifying the exact effect used is unlikely - though someone might replicate it to some degree. Simple answer would be that they used a digital filter...

Comment: Like @DustinDavis says, it sounds like reverb and echo, but I'm also hearing some "phase shift". I believe it emphasizes one frequency band, then a higher frequency, then a higher frequency, up to the top of the range, and then from the top of the range it emphasizes a lower frequency, then an even lower one, and so on to the bottom of the range we can hear.

Comment: @BrettFromLA the effect you describe is not a phase shift but a phaser effect.

Comment: It sounds a bit like a very subtle vocoder almost. Like it's been reconstructed somehow.